# Mysql to delete from one table using condition from two tables

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, delete-row

I am using this code/query to delete bogus users using a list from 'bogus' table
and Obviously this query is not correct and shows error: **Unknown column 'bogus.user' in 'where clause'** 
Consider that tables sample and bogus have ONLY ONE COLUMN each and I want to **delete** rows from *sample* table only retaining the data of table *bogus*.

```
delete from sample where sample.user=bogus.user;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
 delete from sample where sample.user in (SELECT user FROM bogus);
```

I think that's the savest way. It's probably possible to put both tables in a single statment without a join or nested select. But If you do that wrong you risk deleting both tables content. Thus I'd say it's better to do it this way.

Comment: Thanks for explaining about it. It works as expected :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to join for this

```
delete s from sample s
join bogus b on b.user = s.user
```

Answer (score 0):

```
delete from sample where user in (select user from bogus)
```